# Perl script not able to connect to Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, perl

I am getting the below error message while executing my Perl script.
Below is the error message that I am getting while compiling my scripts.

**install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load '/xxx/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/sun4-solaris/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' 
for module DBD::Oracle: ld.so.1: perl: fatal: libclntsh.so.10.1: open failed: No such file or directory at 
/xxx/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.0/sun4-solaris/DynaLoader.pm line 203.
 at (eval 99) line 3
Compilation failed in require at (eval 99) line 3.
Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected
 at /xxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/XXXX/CommonOracle.pm line 71**

Recently Oracle have been upgraded from 10.2 to 11.0 in my system. Please help me to fix the issue? I am not the administrator of my system. Do i need to change  LD_LIBRARRY_PATH? I am using Solaris OS.

Comment: Here you find  something on [ask] and how to build a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have forgotten to ask a question. Let's assume it's "how can I fix this?"

Communicating with a database requires a number of things to be installed on your system.

- You need the client libraries for the database system that you're using. This will be shared object (.so) files that are probably somewhere under /usr/lib.
- You will need the Perl Database driver for your database engine (in your case, this is DBD::Oracle). If you install this by building it from scratch (as the `cpan` or `cpanm` commands do) then you'll almost certainly also need the development version of the above-mentioned client libraries. If you're installing pre-built binary versions (.rpm or .apt on Linux - I don't know the equivalent for Solaris) then you won't need these.
- You will need the Perl DBI library.

It looks to me like DBD::Oracle is installed. And that means that DBI will be installed as well. But DBD::Oracle is having trouble finding the client libraries. This is surprising as they will hae been needed to install DBD::Oracle.

So, I suspect that either the Oracle client libraries are no longer installed or they are installed, but not in the place where DBD::Oracle is looking for them.

How was DBD::Oracle installed? Do you have a log of that installation that you can inspect for errors?

Comment: thank you for your response. But I don't have the log of installation. The perl modules are installed . I will try and check the Perl DBI library again. Will it impact if the Oracle version is upgraded?

Comment: It's not the DBI library that's the problem. It seems to be the Oracle client libraries. I'd try to reinstall DBD::Oracle and see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. The lib file "libclntsh.so.10.1" was missing in the library path. I have copied the file and the issue was resolved